How to rotate a region with an image
I want to rotate an image with a specific region. For example, if I rotate the image of 30 degrees, I want the regions to follow it.
I've tried the rotate_image function, and it does the job for the image, but not for the region.

You will have to explain yourself better. I don’t know what you mean by the regions following the image. What type of regions are these? How are they defined?

note: halcon is a commercial program for machine vision. commercial MV presents graphical "programming" to its user.

By defining homogeneous matrices, you can use them on different object types:
read_image (Image, 'fabrik') 
gen_rectangle1 (Rectangle, 30, 20, 100, 200)

hom_mat2d_identity (HomMat2DIdentity) 
hom_mat2d_rotate (HomMat2DIdentity, 0.1, 0, 0, HomMat2DRotate)

affine_trans_image (Image, ImageAffineTrans, HomMat2DRotate, 'constant', 'false') 
affine_trans_region (Rectangle, RegionAffineTrans, HomMat2DRotate, 'nearest_neighbor')

